# Replacing wrong characters (encoding issues ?)

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, decoding

I am working on a csv file with text data and for some reason some characters are "corrupted".

```
Add another song to the Cita RomГЎntica playlist. ,AddToPlaylist
add The Greyest of Blue Skies in Indie EspaГ±ol my playlist,AddToPlaylist
```

I can't figure how to transform those weird combinations into the actual characters (respectively, á and ñ).

I have tried some decoding modules but I don't really know what I am doing despite my research (i don't know what kind of format or so is responsible of the issue).

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: first you have to know what encoding uses this file and later you can use this encoding to open file - `open(...., encoding=...)`

Comment: do you use MacOS? It may uses different encoding `utf-8` then `Windows` and `Linux` and it can make problem to load it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google `decode ГЎ` I found some page which mentioned encoding `cp1251`

If I run this code

```
text = 'ГЎ Г±'

converted = text.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')

print(converted)
```

then I get correct text

```
á ñ
```

So it can means your file use encoding `cp1251` and you should use this encoding when you read csv - `open(..., encoding="cp1251")` or `pandas.read_csv(..., encoding="cp1251")`

OR it can means that your Python use `cp1251` instead of `utf-8` as default encoding to read data  and you should set `utf-8` manually -
`open(..., encoding="utf-8")` or `pandas.read_csv(..., encoding="utf-8")`